# Requested data cannot be store inside variable in Java

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

I am trying getting data from an API using volley. I am trying to store it as a global variable, but it always returns null. Why?

Here is my sample code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {

                try {
                    if (response.getString("action").equals("success")) {

                        checkInTime = response.getString("checkin");
                        checkOutTime = response.getString("chekout");

                        System.out.println(response);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }, Throwable::printStackTrace);

    Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this).add(jsonRequest);
```

What is the problem here?

here is my api json response

```
{"action":"success","checkin":"08:30:25","chekout":"blank"}
```

Comment: What always returns null?

Comment: Please add json response. and also a little more detail for the problem

Comment: provide your API response with question.

Comment: Api Response Posted . My question I cannot store response data

Comment: Please if possible provide your variable related code e.g where you are getting your variable null or where you are using your variable. Because the code you provide is not enough to track you issue.

Comment: You are aware that `chekout` should have been `checkout`?

Comment: So, what is the problem here? Did you mean the variables of `checkInTime` and `checkOutTime` are null? Are they ***final*** and ***global*** enough?

Comment: I also declared as Final But doesnt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not working out of the request parenthesis
because this variable is temporary and it can be null if no data found.

So you have to write looks like

```
public static String checkInTime = "";
public static String checkOutTime = "";
```

After declaring global variable of String you can store data and can access from anywhere

```
checkInTime = response.getString("checkin");
checkOutTime = response.getString("chekout");
```

Its actually working for me

Answer (score 1):

From the context you provided I guess you have a problem with some of these lines:
if (response.getString("action").equals("success")) {

```
                    checkInTime = response.getString("checkin");
                    checkOutTime = response.getString("chekout");
```

Reason 1 - you are not entering the if body
Reason 2 - you are not getting the response values properly

Try to debug the function
If I need to debug it I will:

- Print the response before the IF statement
- Print these values:

  `response.getString("action")     checkInTime = response.getString("checkin");     checkOutTime = response.getString("chekout");`

Comment: But I want it as global

Answer (score -1):

If it's being done from an Activity:

create a variable, e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private String checkInTime;
```

Then in the code you posted above, add:

```
                if (response.getString("action").equals("success")) {

                    this.checkInTime = response.getString("checkin");
```

Now try to access it from other places.

**If it's not what you are looking for, please update the question with the relevant code regarding your global variable.**

Comment: Not working show null